# Finding all hyperlinks (<a>, </a>) and creating a list of this

Tags: python

so I have found all hyperlinks of a certain paragraph and it has the following format:

```
"<p>Source: <a href=""www.source1.com"">Source 1</a>, <a href=""www.secondsource.com"">Second source</a>, <a href=""www.andthisisthelastone.com"">Third source</a></p>"
```

All paragraphs have their own hyperlinks that are stored as above string in a dataframe, hence each paragraph has its own row and strings that consist of hyperlinks.

Now I am trying to making a list of it with the following format:

```
['Source 1#www.source1.com', 'Second source#www.secondsource.com', 'Third source#www.andthisisthelastone.com'
```

I came up with the following:

```
hyperlinks = []
    for string in string_hyperlinks:
        links.append(re.findall(r'(https?://[^\s]+)', string))
```

Which gives the following generalized result:

```
['www.source.com"">Source 1</a>', 'www.secondsource.com"">Second source', 'www.andthisisthelastsource.com"">Third source</a></p>']
```

How can I convert it to the correct format?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a question mark in your regex after '+', like this
`(https?://[^\s]+?)`

Comment: This doesn't help with the rest of the formatting

Answer (score 0):

*The HTML code you provided is not a valid one. Please check.*

You could use `BeautifulSoup` to select all the `<a>` tags and extract the data you need and put them in a list.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = '''<p>Source: <a href="www.source1.com">Source 1</a>, <a href="www.secondsource.com">Second source</a>, <a href="www.andthisisthelastone.com">Third source</a></p>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(s, 'html.parser')
res = []
atags = soup.findAll('a')

for i in atags:
    tex = i.text.strip()
    href = i['href']
    res.append(f'{tex}#{href}')
print(res)
```

```
['Source 1#www.source1.com', 'Second source#www.secondsource.com', 'Third source#www.andthisisthelastone.com']
```